# Не получается установить vue js, ошибка permission denied

Tags: linux, vue.js, npm, linux-mint

Не получается установить vue js! В Linux mint через терминал ввожу команду

> npm install -g vue-cli

В результате получаю ошибку:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/vue-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/vue-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/vue-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/vue-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-11-25T08_44_15_166Z-debug.log
```

Пробовал через терминал линукса, через терминал webstorm - везде одна и та же ошибка.

Comment: `EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/vue-cli'` как бы говорит нам, что не хватает прав.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте права администратора для совершения данного действия.

```
sudo su
```

чтобы переключится на root, или же

```
sudo npm install -g vue-cli
```

Чтобы выполнить конкретную команду с root правами, которые нужны npm.
В обоих случаях может потребоваться ввести пароль, который не отображается при вводе (особенность Linux дистрибутивов).